# Cuda::Entry function uses too much local data

Tags: cuda, tesla

I am trying to run one algorithm for Polygon Intersection on Tesla C2075.But when I try to compile this algorithm, the compiler is giving me error :`"Entry Function 'Polygon_Intersection'uses too much local data(0x40e8 bytes,0x4000)`.

My algorithm is little bit complex and it make use of lots of local variable inside the kernel.
So my question is ,Is there any way to solve this problem like Can I use Global memory for local variable declaration for each kernel or somehow use the shared memory?

Comment: What gpu are you using? If you have a Fermi or Kepler device, you have the option of using dynamically heap memory too.

Comment: @ talonmies :I am using Tesla C2075 device which is Fermi device.I tried using dynamically heap memory (by using malloc) but it gave compile error saying "host function 'malloc' is not supported).

Comment: You need to compile with `arch=sm_20`for that GPU

Comment: Did `-arch=sm_20` fix your issue, @uci_grad? If not, please post some code so we can help you.

Comment: @harrism : Yes arch=sm_20 solves my issue.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with `-arch=sm_20` to enable device-side `malloc` so that you can use heap memory for thread-local data.

Comment: I have same problem , but it gives error sh: g++: not found. 
I didn't find any information about -arch , can you give some information or help ?
also I used it like this  nvcc -arch=sm_20 main.cu , It' right or not? :) , thanks 
regards

Comment: This is not the same problem. You need to submit a separate question. It sounds like you have a broken compiler toolchain installation.